# Determine whether if $42\nmid 84$ or for any integer $a$ we have that $a \equiv{a+4}\pmod 4$is true

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have the following question: Determine whether if $42\nmid 84$ or for any integer $a$ we have that $a\equiv{a+4}\pmod4$ is true. By intution I would say that it's $42 \nmid 84$ that's true, since the division between $42$ and $84$ does not produce a whole number and therefore it's the correct answer. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False $\implies$ anything (true or false).

In other words:

- The statement "False $\implies$ True" is true
- The statement "False $\implies$ False" is true

Since $42\nmid84$ is false, the statement is true **regardless** of the RHS.

For example:

- The statement "$42\nmid84\implies\forall{a}\in\mathbb{Z}:a\equiv{a+4}\pmod4$" is true
- The statement "$42\nmid84\implies\exists{a}\in\mathbb{Z}:a\not\equiv{a+4}\pmod4$" is true

Comment: Thank you. But I am still not exactly sure why 42 ∤ 84 is false? Isn't it true since the division produces a non whole number?

Comment: @e563e7d4: $42\nmid84\iff42\text{ does not divide }84\iff\frac{84}{42}\not\in\mathbb{Z}\iff2\not\in\mathbb{Z}\iff\text{ false}$.

Comment: $42\nmid84$ means "42 doesn't divide 84" since, which is false since 42 DOES divide 84.

Comment: @kub0x: So...? How exactly is that different from what I wrote???

Comment: Sorry, I am obviously missing some understanding regarding divisibility. But how is 42 divisible by 84 when that yields 0.5?

Comment: @barakmanos: Is the same thing. 84 divided by 42 produces an integer number (quotient) so the statement $42\nmid84$ is false, as it would have to produce a rational number.

Comment: @e563e7d4: Please read my comment above carefully. Focus on the textual part **"$42$ does not divide $84$"**. What you are probably missing about *divisibility*, is the direction of the "$\mid$" operator: The expression "$x\mid y$" mean "$x$ divides $y$", **NOT** "$x$ is divisible by $y$". Same thing goes for the "$\nmid$" operator.

Comment: @e563e7d4 Is not $\frac{42}{84}$. $42|84$ is $\frac{84}{42}$.

Comment: @kub0x: 1. If it's the same thing, than why did you post that comment to begin with? 2. Your usage of the term "**rational**" is wrong in this context, since an integer is also rational. The correct explanation should be using the term "**non-integer**".

Comment: @e563e7d4: You're welcome :)